# gcolor2 package missing in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

This little tool has been around for at least a decade, but it suddenly [appears to be missing](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gcolor2). It's in debian stable, so I figured it would get inherited. Does anyone know if it was intentionally removed, and if so where I can learn more?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1603897 and https://launchpad.net/~evertiro/+archive/ubuntu/gcolor3. Gedit and Geany both have something very similar to gcolor2 as part of their applications. There's also `gpick` if you can figure out how it works.

Comment: Package has been removed from Debian [before](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gcolor2) feature freeze happens in Ubuntu.

Comment: Debian bug giving reasons for removal: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=869157

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is not too difficult to install it manually (from 16.04 LTS *xenial* repository):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcolor2/gcolor2_0.4-2.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gcolor2_0.4-2.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

And then use it as before:

[image: gcolor2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

---

Notes:

1. modern alternative - [`gcolor3`](https://www.hjdskes.nl/projects/gcolor3/#flatpak) is packaged in very few distributions.
(see [at repology.org](https://repology.org/metapackage/gcolor3/versions)).
2. on Ubuntu `gcolor3` is installable from [`ppa:evertiro/gcolor3`](https://launchpad.net/~evertiro/+archive/ubuntu/gcolor3).
3. currently `gcolor3` does not have broad list of predefined colors (see above, reported [bug 110 to developer](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/gcolor3/issues/110)).
4. another alternative is KColorChooser, it is installable from repository as `kcolorchooser` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kcolorchooser), but it does not have list of named colors.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have gcolor2 in Kubuntu 18.04! I like it better than `kcolorchooser`. There's a ppa for gcolor3 but gcolor2 is quite enough.

Comment: PPA works great on 18.04! Wasn't aware that they had reworked the project as v3

Comment: In 18.04, geany and gedit also include a color chooser very much like gcolor3 (because they don't provide a dropdown list of named colors).

Comment: You might want to change that to the HTTPS version of the link. I cannot do a single character edit to your post.

Comment: gcolor3 is the best!

Comment: This is similar and already in the repository: sudo apt install kcolorchooser

Comment: @LonnieBest thanks, but it does not have named color list.

Answer (score 5):

`zenity --color-selection` provides a no-frills color-dialog. In 19.04, but not in 18.04, the "dropper" in the top-left corner allows you to click on any item on your desktop.:

[image: Zenity as a color-dialog]

---

There's also *yad* which is said to offer [more features](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/yad-zenity-on-steroids-display.html) than zenity. And the version in 1**8**.04 comes with a dropper to allow you to pick a color from any item on the desktop:

```
yad --color
```

[image: Yad with color-picker]

Answer (score 2):

If you would care about a gcolor2 alternative, I am recommending Gpick.

[image: Gpick]

It's easy to use and has a lot of features, which you can find in [Gpick's website](http://www.gpick.org/). You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt install gpick
```