# Retrieve background color in ubuntu mate

Tags: themes, mate, colors

I am using Ubuntu mate 18.04.3 LTS.

I am quite fond of my background color and would like to use it on another machine.  Where can I find the exact color that is used?  When I go into the Control center and get the Appearance Preferences window, and then the Background tab, I see my color, but when I click on my background color next to Color: Solid color, I get a color selector that is positioned on a red color, while I want a blue color, so that is not the current one.

Comment: If you just want to know the hex or rgb code for any color on your desktop look at the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073990/gcolor2-package-missing-in-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a color picker to select the exact color you need.

Install GColor2 using `sudo apt install gcolor2` and then launch it.
Click the color picker icon which will turn your cursor into a color picker, then click on the background color you want to pick.

See screenshot below:

[image: GColor2 Color picker]

Comment: See [gcolor2 package missing in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1073990/248158) for how to get around gcolor2 not being included by default in 18.04 and newer.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is about 18.04 and *gcolor2* isn't available by default in 18.04. You can confirm that by looking at https://packages.ubuntu.com/. Two days ago, I posted a link to a question dealing with exactly this issue and how to work around it.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your Question Correctly.. you want to know what is the color used for desktop background which is already set in any way.

See the below Image, I have selected it via preset options under Background..
[image]

The colors can be easily retrived with `gsettings` or `dconf-editor`

```
gsettings get org.mate.background color-shading-type
gsettings get org.mate.background primary-color
gsettings get org.mate.background secondary-color
```

Example:

```
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$  gsettings get org.mate.background color-shading-type
'vertical-gradient'
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ gsettings get org.mate.background primary-color
'rgb(88,145,188)'
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ gsettings get org.mate.background secondary-color
'rgb(60,143,37)'
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~
```

Install `dconf-editor` if not yet installed, with the below command

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

[image]

from the above results the colors are rgb(88,145,188) and rgb(60,143,37)

---

[image]

[image]