# How can I know what software is provided by Ubuntu Mate's Boutique without downloading Ubuntu Mate itself?

Tags: software-center, mate

I want to know what software is offered in Ubuntu Mate's Boutique without downloading Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

How can I do so?

The reason is to settle a doubt about the availability of the *gcolor2* package.

As the image below shows, it is absent from the regular Bionic repositories:

[image: gcolor2 is only listed as being in xenial]

Image sourced from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gcolor2&searchon=names).

Furthermore Debian removed *gcolor2* according to 
[RM: gcolor2 -- ROM; RoM, RoQA, dead-upstream, unmaintained, better alternatives available](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=869157) dated Fri, 21 Jul 2017 05:12:02 UTC well before Bionic was released (26 April 2018).

Could it perhaps somehow be offered via Ubuntu Mate's Software Boutique? The Software Boutique is [described here](https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/software-boutique/) as

> An easy-to-use software distribution program for Ubuntu MATE. The team
>   curates a selection of tried & tested applications that integrate well
>   with the Ubuntu MATE desktop.

Answer (score 2):

One can get an idea of the software offered by Ubuntu Mate's Software Boutique by downloading the contents of [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ubuntu-mate/ubuntu-mate-welcome-legacy/master/data/js/applications.json) as *sb.html* and then running

```
grep -n name sb.html
```

The list has 5782 entries currently. *gcolor2* isn't one of them.

---

However, in [gcolor2 package missing in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1073990), there's [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073995) describing how *gcolor2* can be installed in *any* 18.04 flavor by using the package from the xenial repository.

Comment: Just as side note - you can install Software Boutique [as a Snap](https://snapcraft.io/software-boutique) on any Ubuntu with `sudo snap install software-boutique --classic` to get its user-friendly interface.